# is_page() conditional not working inside an AJAX function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am doing filtering posts using ajax.

I wish $ array was different for pages "Products" and "Faq"

If this is executed within an ajax request, is_page() won't be set. the page you're making the request from was a previous request. you need to set something on the originating page to pass with your ajax request to let it know it's for your special case page.

**functions.php**

```
function load_scripts() {
    
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/vendor/jquery/main.js', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, true );
  
  wp_localize_script( 'ajax', 'wp_ajax',
      array( 
          'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
          'is_page'  => is_page( 420 ), // Whatever you want to pass. Add as many key pairs as needed.
          )
  );
  
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_filter', 'filter_ajax' );


function filter_ajax() {
  
$category = $_POST['category'];

if(isset($_POST['is_page']) && $_POST['is_page'] === 'faq'){
      $cat__in = 10;
      print_r(  $_POST );
      echo "FAQ";

  } else{
    $cat__in = 4;
    print_r(  $_POST );
    echo "Products";
  }
  
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 50,
'category__in' => $cat__in,
);

if(isset($category)) {

  $args['category__in'] = array($category);
}


      $query = new WP_Query($args);

      if($query->have_posts()) :
          while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
              the_title('<h2>', '</h2>');
              the_content('<p>', '</p>');
          endwhile;
      endif;
          wp_reset_postdata(); 
  die();
}
```

**faq.php**

```
<div class="js-filter">
    <?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'child_of' => 10,
    'exclude' => array(1),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query(array( 'cat' => 10 ));

    if($query->have_posts()) :
        while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            the_title('<h2>', '</h2>');
            the_content('<p>', '</p>');
        endwhile;
        endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
<div class="categories">

<ul>
    <?php 
        $cat_args = array(
            'exclude' => array(1),
            'child_of' => 10
        );
        ?>

<?php 
global $post;
$category = reset(get_the_category($post->ID));
$category_id = $category->cat_ID;
?>

        <li class="js-filter-item"><a href="#">All</a></li>

        <?php $categories = get_categories($cat_args); foreach($categories as $cat) : ?>
        <li class="js-filter-item"><a data-category="<?= $cat->term_id; ?>" href="<?= get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?= $cat->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

**products.php**

```
<div class="js-filter">
    <?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'child_of' => 6,
    'exclude' => array(1,10),
    );

    $query = new WP_Query(array( 'cat' => 6 ));

    if($query->have_posts()) :
        while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            the_title('<h2>', '</h2>');
            the_content('<p>', '</p>');
        endwhile;
        endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
<div class="categories">

<ul>
    <?php 
        $cat_args = array(
            'exclude' => array(1,10),
            'child_of' => 6
        );
        ?>

<?php 
global $post;
$category = reset(get_the_category($post->ID));
$category_id = $category->cat_ID;
?>

        <li class="js-filter-item"><a href="#">All</a></li>

        <?php $categories = get_categories($cat_args); foreach($categories as $cat) : ?>
        <li class="js-filter-item"><a data-category="<?= $cat->term_id; ?>" href="<?= get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?= $cat->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

**main.js**

```
 jQuery(function($){
    $(document).on('click', '.js-filter-item > a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var category = $(this).data('category');

        $.ajax({
            url: wp_ajax.ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'filter',
                is_page: wp_ajax.is_page, // This param will be passed to your ajax function.
                category: category,
                pageslug: location.pathname.replace(/\//g,'')
            },
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result) {
                $('.js-filter').html(result);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                console.warn(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

do you have any idea how to solve it? After clicking on the "All" button, it displays posts from the "ID = 6" category

Comment: Manual (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) says that the parameter must be (int|string|int[]|string[]) (Optional) Page ID, title, slug, or array of such to check against. So try to use the id of the page and not the title or slug.

Comment: add it to your localize script and pass it with ajax.

Comment: I tried with `(is_page(420) )` but it didn't work. How do I change my `main.js` file to make the `ID` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your parameter by using the localize script feature.  Since the page isn't passed to your ajax function, you need to set your params in localize script, then pass to your ajax as part of the localized array.

```
function load_scripts() {
    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/vendor/jquery/main.js', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, true );
    
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax', 'wp_ajax',
        array( 
            'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'is_page'  => is_page( 420 ), // Whatever you want to pass. Add as many key pairs as needed.
            )
    );
    
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

In the case above, `is_page` is either true or false, and will pass to your javascript via the localized script.  So in the JS file, `wp_ajax.is_page` will be either true or false (you can view this by inspecting your js object on the page. It should be a 0 or a 1.

If you wanted to pass other objects, you can create as many items to your array and then pass to your js template.

Your AJAX:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).on('click', '.js-filter-item > a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var category = $(this).data('category');

        $.ajax({
            url: wp_ajax.ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'filter',
                is_page: wp_ajax.is_page, // This param will be passed to your ajax function.
                category: category,
                pageslug: location.pathname.replace(/\//g,'')
            },
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result) {
                $('.js-filter').html(result);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                console.warn(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Then in your updated php ajax action.

```
function filter_ajax() {
    
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    // If it's page 420... then $_POST['is_page'] will equal a string 1.
    if ( isset( $_POST['is_page'] ) && $_POST['is_page'] === '1' ) {
        $cat__in = 10;
        print_r( $_POST );
        echo "FAQ";
        
    } else {
        $cat__in = 4;
        print_r( $_POST );
        echo "Products";
    }
    // .... rest of function
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I implemented code but it still doesn't work. check how I edited it.

Comment: You have to update your php ajax action to use `$_POST['is_page']` now that you've passed it back to your function.

Comment: `$_POST['is_page']` is a boolean, not an integer.  You will need to debug your $_POST data, but it should be either a 1 or a 0

Comment: I updated the function. Please take a look.

Comment: Can you put the code in your post? I got a little lost ...

Comment: Added more detail.  I think it should be pretty clear now. - remember that your localized script will be passed to the frontend as "CDATA" so you can just go inspect the page and search for `wp_ajax` and find that "is_page":"1" or "0" but it will be passed as a string in $_POST data.

Answer (score 1):

is_page() is not supposed to work in wp_ajax_ functions.
Check this answer: [Why doesn't is_page(id) work in functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172081/why-doesnt-is-pageid-work-in-functions-php)

> is_page() relies on a complete global $wp_query object. If you call it before the action template_redirect has been fired, it might be impossible to get that data.

Instead of using is_page(), you can pass the slug as ajax data array value.

To pass as slug, edit main.js to replace

```
data: { action: 'filter', category: category },
```

with

```
data: { 
  action: 'filter', 
  category: category, 
  pageslug: location.pathname.replace(/\//g,'') 
},
```

Then, in functions.php in filter_ajax() function, replace

```
if (is_page('faq'))
```

with

```
if(isset($_POST['pageslug']) && $_POST['pageslug'] === 'faq')
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but it doesn't work. Edited functions.php and main.js in the post so you can see how I used it.

Comment: @code_hub, you are using $_POST['is_page'] while my suggestion was $_POST['pageslug']